# ¿Por qué en la documentación de Java dice que la precedencia es post-incremento antes que pre-incremento?

Tags: java, variables, operador, operador-incremento

Tengo una duda sobre la precedencia de a++ y ++a.
Veo que en la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) pone que la precedencia es post sobre pre, pero al ejecutar:

```
int a = 5;
double b = (double) ++a / a++;
System.out.println(b);      // 1.0
```

Observo que se ejecuta en orden de aparición (de izquierda a derecha).
¿Qué me estoy perdiendo?

Esta tabla es la de la documentación de Oracle.

[image: Precedencia de operadores, documentación Oracle]

Estoy leyendo el libro de OCP Oracle Certified 11.
Cito:

```
int lion = 3;
int tiger = ++lion * 5 / lion--;
System.out.println("lion is " + lion);
System.out.println("tiger is " + tiger);
```

> This one is more complicated than the previous example
> because lion is modified two times on the same line. Each time
> it is modified, the value of lion changes, with different values
> being assigned to the variable. As you’ll recall from our
> discussion on operator precedence, order of operation plays an
> important part in evaluating this example.
> So how do you read this code? ***First, lion is decremented**. We
> can simplify this:

```
int tiger = ++lion * 5 / 3; // lion assigned value of 2
```

> ***Next, lion is incremented** with the new value of 3 used in the
> expression, leading to this:

```
int tiger = 3 * 5 / 3; // lion assigned value of 3
```

> Finally, we evaluate multiplication and division from left to
> right. The product of the first two numbers is 15. The divisor 3
> divides 15 evenly, resulting in an assignment of 5 to tiger. The
> result is then printed:

```
lion is 3
tiger is 5
```

Estoy de acuerdo en que en el ejemplo que doy se ejecute antes el pre-incremento y después el post-incremento.

Lo que necesito saber es por qué en esas tablas y en el libro de preparación del OCP aparece otra versión de la película.

Comment: En esta línea ++a  incrementa el valor y cuando se usa a++; el valor ya se encuentra incrementado, por esa razón tienes como resultado 1.0 ( 6 / 6 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación de Java](https://The%20Java%20programming%20language%20guarantees%20that%20every%20operand%20of%20an%20operator%20(except%20the%20conditional%20operators%20&&,%20%7C%7C,%20and%20?%20:)%20appears%20to%20be%20fully%20evaluated%20before%20any%20part%20of%20the%20operation%20itself%20is%20performed.), garantiza que los **operandos** de los operadores serán evaluados en un orden específico. Nótese que no habla directamente de los operadores.

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

También dice que:

1. En el caso de un operador binario, el operando izquierdo será completamente evaluado antes que el derecho. <sup>[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7:%7E:text=The%20left%2Dhand%20operand%20of%20a%20binary%20operator%20appears%20to%20be%20fully%20evaluated%20before%20any%20part%20of%20the%20right%2Dhand%20operand%20is%20evaluated.)</sup>
2. Todos los operandos de un operador serán completamente evaluados antes de efectuar la operación (a excepción de los operadores `&&`, `||` y `? :`). <sup>[2](https://The%20Java%20programming%20language%20guarantees%20that%20every%20operand%20of%20an%20operator%20(except%20the%20conditional%20operators%20&&,%20%7C%7C,%20and%20?%20:)%20appears%20to%20be%20fully%20evaluated%20before%20any%20part%20of%20the%20operation%20itself%20is%20performed.)</sup>

Siguiendo esta lógica, en la expresión `++a / a++`, primero se evalúa `++a` y luego `a++`.

Posiblemente te preguntes, ¿Entonces como aplica la precedencia de operadores?

En pocas palabras, es la manera en que Java asocia por defecto.

Si todavía no estás seguro, mira este ejemplo de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992012/13419694):

```
class Test
{
    public static int a(){ System.out.println("a"); return 2; }
    public static int b(){ System.out.println("b"); return 3; }
    public static int c(){ System.out.println("c"); return 4; }
        
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(a() + b() * c());
        // Explícitamente
        System.out.println(a() + (b() * c()));
    }
}
```

La salida indica que la expresión se evaluó de izquierda a derecha:

```
a
b
c
14
a
b
c
14
```

---

Recuerda que lo mejor es escribir código que puedas mantener. Especialmente cuando trabajas en equipo. Además cuando te olvides como funcionaba puedes continuar sin un gran esfuerzo.

Comment: Mucho mejor ahora. Gracias.

¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo explícito de asociación por defecto con operadores unarios?

Comment: @sinosuke11 alguna vez expresión que tengas en mente? La tuya (que más o menos está en la respuesta) se asocia de esta manera: `(++a) / (a++)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Para finalizar, ¿ me podrías poner un ejemplo de precedencia de post-incremento antes de pre- incremento en que se vea claro que se aplica?

Comment: Podría ser una expresión como ++a++ pero no compilará. Aunque puedes comprobar que se cumple la precedencia de la tabla viendo que los errores que genera usando la asociación implícita y explícita son los mismos. https://ideone.com/cxcnln

Comment: La duda ha quedado resuelta.  Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

**Post-incremento** (`a++`): Evalúa la expresión con el valor actual de la variable, y luego incrementa la variable.

**Pre-incremento** (`++a`): Incrementa la variable, y luego evalúa la expresión con el valor de la variable incrementada.

Cuando se habla de precedencia de estos dos operadores de izquierda a derecha significa el orden en que se van a ir evaluando en la expresión:

1. Tenemos `++a / a++`. Empiezo de izquierda a derecha. ¿Quién tiene mayor precedencia según la tabla entre `++a` y `/`. Pues `++a`. Entonces evalúo `++a` y lo sustituyo. Queda `6 / a++` con `a = 6`.
2. Tenemos ahora `6 / a++`. ¿Entre `/` y `a++` quien tiene mayor precedencia? Según la tabla `a++`, por tanto sustituyo `a` y luego incremento. Queda `6 / 6` con `a = 7`.
3. Finalmente `6 / 6 = 1`.

---

### Contraejemplo al libro

Suponga se tiene:

```
int lion = 3;
int tiger = ++lion * 5 / lion++;
System.out.println("lion is " + lion);
System.out.println("tiger is " + tiger);
```

Basado en el razonamiento de **OCP Oracle Certified 11**, primero `lion` es incrementado (`lion++`):

```
int tiger = ++lion * 5 / 3; // El valor de lion ahora es  4
```

Luego:

```
int tiger = 5 * 5 / 3; // El valor de lion ahora es  5
```

Finalmente `5 * 5 / 3 = 8`, quedando "supuestamente" `tiger = 8`, pero [al correr el programa](https://onlinegdb.com/rJgH6SmA3H):

```
lion is 5
tiger is 5
```

**Conclusión**: La documentación oficial siempre es mejor que cualquier libro.

Comment: Disculpad el error al escribir preferencia en lugar de precedencia. Corregido.

La duda es sobre el texto de la documentación del enlace.

En la tabla "Operator Precedence" pone que hay precedencia de post-incremento sobre pre-incremento.
Como tú bien dices y yo entiendo, se ejecuta primero el pre-incremento pero ahí es donde me aborda la duda con la documentación.

¿Es errónea o no la estoy interpretando bien?
Échale un ojo, por favor.

Comment: @JoseRamonHidalgo justo edité mi pregunta para aclarar eso. Lee lo que te acabo de colocar y me dices. Por cierto, edita también el título.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. Estoy casi seguro de que entiendo como usar ambos pero lo que no entiendo es porque la documentación y ejemplos de la preparación del OCP escriben otra cosa.

He editado la pregunta para ser más concreto.

Comment: Si ejecuto la operación de `int b = ++a / a++` , según la documentación y el libro sería:
`b = ++a / 5`
`b= 7 / 5`, lo cual no es 1.0

Comment: @sinosuke11 ahí te puse un contraejemplo que contradice al libro. Guíate por la documentación oficial.

Comment: @JaimeFernandez Gracias por el contraejemplo al libro que es es lo mismo que yo observo.
 
La cosa es que creo ver y entender que la documentación oficial no contradice al libro. 
La tabla de Oracle que pongo en la pregunta original se ajusta al libro en cuestión, primero post y después pre. 
Algo curioso...

Comment: @sinosuke11 es curioso, porque ese ejemplo que citas (a menos que lo hayas referenciado mal) lleva a resultados erróneos como te mostré cambiando simplemente el -- por el ++.

Comment: @JaimeFernandez está copiado y pegado tal cual y aprecio lo mismo que tú.
Confuso.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes saber es:

El **pre-incremento**: Usamos ++a en nuestra declaración si queremos incrementar el valor de a en 1 y luego usarlo en nuestra declaración.

```
int a = 0;
System.out.println(++a); //Aquí el valor se incrementa, sería 1.
System.out.println(a); //Aquí el valor es 1.
```

El **post-incremento** : Usamos a++ en nuestra declaración si queremos usar el valor actual, y luego queremos incrementar el valor de a en 1.

```
int a = 0;
System.out.println(a++); //Aquí el valor sería 0, se incrementa en la siguiente línea.
System.out.println(a);  //Aquí el valor se incrementó, es 1.
```

---

Por lo tanto, la razón por la que obtienes como resultado 1.0 es porque primeramente se incrementa el valor (++a) y posteriormente el valor de a++ ya tiene el valor incrementado (6 / 6) :

```
    double a = 5;
    double b = (double) ++a / a++; //En esta linea el valor de ++a sería 6 y el valor de a++ ahora sería 6 también.
    System.out.println(b); // Obtienes 1.0
```

En este otro caso de ejemplo la división sería  `5/6`:

```
    int a = 5;
    double b = (double) a++ / ++a; //En esta línea el valor de a++ sería 5 (ya que se incrementaría en la siguiente línea), pero el valor de ++a  incrementaría el valor de "a" a 6.
    System.out.println(b);
```